# linq SelectMany dates

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on building this viewmodel but I am unsure how to select all the ListOfMeetingDates in this example below.  I also need to format the string into the full month. Any help would be great.

```
List<Meeting> Meeting = new List<Meeting>();
List<MeetingDates> ListOfMeetingDates = new List<MeetingDates>();
ListOfMeetingDates.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 1, StartDate= "11-1-2020"});
ListOfMeetingDates.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 2, StartDate = "11-2-2020" });
Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { Meetingid = 1, MeetingName="a",ListOfMeetingDates= ListOfMeetingDates });
ListOfMeetingDates.Clear();
ListOfMeetingDates.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 3, StartDate = "11-5-2020" });
Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { Meetingid = 2, MeetingName = "b", ListOfMeetingDates = ListOfMeetingDates });

var listOfMeetings = Meeting
.Select(x => new MeetingViewModel
    {
    MeetingName = x.MeetingName,
    MeetingDate = x.ListOfMeetingDates.SelectMany(z => z.StartDate)
    }).ToList();


        class Meeting
        {
            public int Meetingid { get; set; }
            public string MeetingName { get; set; }

            public List<MeetingDates> ListOfMeetingDates { get; set; }
        }

        class MeetingDates
        {
            public int MeetingDatesId { get; set; }
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
        }



        class MeetingViewModel
        {
            public string MeetingName { get; set; }
            public string MeetingDate { get; set; }
        }
```

Output I am looking for

```
MeetingName = a
MeetingDate = November 1 2020 - November 2 2020
MeetingName = b
MeetingDate = November 5 2020
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`Enumerable.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-5.0), as in `var latestDate = ListOfMeetingDates.Max(m => m.StartDate);`? W.r.t. "full months", have a look at [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

#### To get only the start and end dates in the string

```cs
var listOfMeetings = Meeting
  .Select(x => new MeetingViewModel
      {
      MeetingName = x.MeetingName,
      MeetingDate = GetDateRangeFormatted(x.MeetingDates)
      })
  .ToList();

private string GetDateRangeFormatted(IEnumerable<MeetingDates> meetingDates)
{
    if (meetingDates.Count() == 0)
        return String.empty;

    if (meetingDates.Count() == 1)
        return meetingDates.First().StartDate;

    // this will only work if the dates are sorted correctly
    return $"{meetingDates.First().StartDate} - {meetingDates.Last().StartDate}";
}
```

#### To get all the dates in the string

```cs
var listOfMeetings = Meeting
  .Select(x => new MeetingViewModel
      {
      MeetingName = x.MeetingName,
      MeetingDate = string.Join(
          " - ", 
          x.ListOfMeetingDates.Select(d => d.StartDate)
      })
  .ToList();
```

I would recommend, though, to change your model a bit, so you can manipulate/format dates better:

```cs
class MeetingDates
{
    public int MeetingDatesId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } // notice DateTime instead of string
}
```

Comment: what if there are three StartDate in the collection?

Comment: What would your output need to look like in that case?

Comment: MeetingDate = November 1 2020 - November 2 2020 - November 3 2020

Comment: oh, in that case it's even simpler - `string.Join` can help, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Meeting> Meeting = new List<Meeting>();
        List<MeetingDates> ListOfMeetingDates1 = new List<MeetingDates>();
        ListOfMeetingDates1.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 1, StartDate = "11-1-2020" });
        ListOfMeetingDates1.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 2, StartDate = "11-2-2020" });
```

ListOfMeetingDates1.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 3, StartDate = "11-3-2020" });
ListOfMeetingDates1.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 4, StartDate = "11-4-2020" });
ListOfMeetingDates1.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 5, StartDate = "11-5-2020" });
Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { Meetingid = 1, MeetingName = "a", ListOfMeetingDates = ListOfMeetingDates1 });

```
        List<MeetingDates> ListOfMeetingDates2 = new List<MeetingDates>();

        ListOfMeetingDates2.Add(new MeetingDates() { MeetingDatesId = 3, StartDate = "11-5-2020" });
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { Meetingid = 2, MeetingName = "b", ListOfMeetingDates = ListOfMeetingDates2 });

         var expectedOutput = Meeting.Select(e => new MeetingViewModel
        {
            MeetingName = e.MeetingName,
            MeetingDates = e.ListOfMeetingDates.Count == 0 ? string.Empty :
                (e.ListOfMeetingDates.Count == 1 ? DateUtilities.ToStringDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(e.ListOfMeetingDates[0].StartDate), "MMMM dd yyyy") :
           e.ListOfMeetingDates.Select(md => md.StartDate).Aggregate((s1, s2) =>
           (!s1.Contains(",") ?
           DateUtilities.ToStringDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(s1), " MMMM dd yyyy") : s1.ToString())
           + "," + DateUtilities.ToStringDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(s2), "MMMM dd yyyy")))
        }).ToList();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}



class Meeting
{
    public int Meetingid { get; set; }
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }

    public List<MeetingDates> ListOfMeetingDates { get; set; }
}

class MeetingDates
{
    public int MeetingDatesId { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
}



class MeetingViewModel
{
    public string MeetingName { get; set; }
    public string MeetingDates { get; set; }
}

public static class DateUtilities
{
    public static string ToStringDateTime(DateTime dateTime, string format)
    {
        return dateTime.ToString(format);
    }
}
```

Comment: what if there are three values in the ListOfMeetingDates ?